# Powershell Exclude Multiple OUs

Tags: powershell

I need to be able to exclude multiple OUs when searching for Active Users in Powershell. The list of OUs is stored in a data table which can be updated when new OUs need excluding. I can't think of a way of excluding these OUs dynamically, i.e. not requiring to update the script in order to add a new

```
(`$_.distinguishedname -notlike "*OU1*")
```

for each OU.

I've been attempting this for a good few hours now with no joy. I've even tried creating the filter by looping through the data table, such as

```
$ToReturn = "(`$_.distinguishedname -notlike ""*$Row[0]*"")"
```

and then add

```
$ToReturn = $ToReturn + " -and (`$_.distinguishedname -notlike ""*$Row[0]*"")"
```

for subsequent exclusions however it ignores the variable.

UPDATE 1: Code to return users::

```
$users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase $SourceOu -Server $Domain -Filter {
        whenCreated -lt $DisableDate
        -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq $False
        }|? {$ExludedOUs}
```

Where $ExcludedOUs is, I need a way of dynamically adding an equivalent of  ($_.distinguishedname -notlike "*OU1*") for each Exclusion in the datatable.

Many thanks in advance!

Lewis

Comment: `""*$Row[0]*""` should be `""*$($Row[0])*""`

Comment: I think we would need more information on how theses exclusions would be stored/retrieved. I'm sure you could build a filter easily enough using something like `'{'+$(($Exclusions |%{"distinguishedname -notlike '$_'"}) -join ' -and ') + '}'` which should net you something like `{distinguishedname -notlike 'X' -and distinguishedname -notlike 'Y'}` for each item in `$Exclusions`.

Comment: Thank you boths for your comments. Mathias - I updated it as suggested but still did not work. I have updated the post to explain further
@TheMadTechnician - It is stored in a SQL table which I can loop through, just don't know how to put it all together! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `-notmatch` and join your exclusions with `|` regex operator:

```
$OURegex = $ExcludedOUs -Join '|'
$users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase $SourceOu -Server $Domain -Filter {
    whenCreated -lt $DisableDate
    -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq $False
    } | Where-Object {$_.DistinguishedName -notmatch $OURegex}
```

Comment: Hi @BenH, I tried your suggestion like below but still does not filter out, Am I doing something wrong?
'  
Function GetListOfExcludedOUs()
{
foreach($Row in $Result.Rows)
            {
                $ToReturnArray += $Row[0]
            }
            return $ToReturnArray
}
$ExludedOUs = GetListOfExcludedOUs -Join '|'
$users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase $SourceOu -Server $Domain -Filter {
        whenCreated -lt $DisableDate
        -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq $False
        }| ? {$_.distinguishedname -notmatch $ExludedOUs}'

Comment: I made a couple of changes as I noticed my code was different to yours and it is now working! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @LewisHoulden Great. Glad it works. If an answer works for it's best practice to accept it.